# How to make powershell wait for exe to install?

Tags: powershell

So i've read every single answer related to this question but none of them seem to be working.

I've got these lines going on in the script:

```
$exe = ".\wls1033_oepe111150_win32.exe"
$AllArgs = @('-mode=silent', '-silent_xml=silent_install.xml', '-log=wls_install.log"')
$check = Start-Process $exe $AllArgs -Wait -Verb runAs
$check.WaitForExit()
```

After this runs I have a regex check on the installed files that replaces some specific strings, but no matter what I try to do it continues to run the regex check while the program is installing.

How can I make it so that the next line doesn't execute until it finishes installing the exe? I've also tried piping to Out-Null with no luck.

Comment: I would suspect that the installer spawn another process for doing the installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a test executable that did the following

```
    Console.WriteLine("In Exe start" + System.DateTime.Now);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("In Exe end" + System.DateTime.Now);
```

Then wrote this powershell script which as expected waits for the exe to finish running before outputting the text "end of ps1" and the time

```
push-location "C:\SRC\PowerShell-Wait-For-Exe\bin\Debug";
$exe = "PowerShell-Wait-For-Exe.exe"  
$proc = (Start-Process $exe -PassThru)
$proc | Wait-Process

Write-Host "end of ps1" + (Get-Date).DateTime
```

This following powershell also correctly waits for the exe to finish.

```
$check = Start-Process $exe $AllArgs -Wait -Verb runas
Write-Host "end of ps1" + (Get-Date).DateTime
```

Adding the WaitForExit call gives me this error.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:1
+ $check.WaitForExit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

However this does work

```
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\PowerShell-Wait-For-Exe\bin\Debug\PowerShell-Wait-For-Exe.exe","");
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo;
$p.Start();
$p.WaitForExit();
Write-Host "end of ps1" + (Get-Date).DateTime
```

I think maybe you are confusing the Start-Process powershell command with the .NET framework Process object

Comment: So it looks like the last one is a winner. The first two didn't seem to work at all. However, I WAS getting the two mixed up. Thanks for that clarification. I guess google isn't quite my friend all the time.